# Adding a cursor with Autocomplete TextField package with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

At the moment, I am using the Autocomplete TextField package inside the appBar of my Flutter application (toggle-able with a magnifying glass icon) to build a search bar. The search bar finds data in a json file. This is my code for the search bar:

```
_searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<Fruit>(
  controller: _searchBarController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Find your fruit here...',
    border: InputBorder.none,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
    filled: true,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context, item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 5.0,
        left: 10.0,
        right: 10.0,
        bottom: 5.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            item.name,
            style: kSearchBarTextStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2.0),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                item.variety,
                style: kSectionSubtitleTextStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Text(
                item.country,
                style: kSectionSubtitleTextStyle,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2.0),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                item.colour,
                style: kSectionSubtitleTextStyle,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  itemFilter: (item, query) {
    return item.searchTerm.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
  },
  itemSorter: (a, b) {
    return a.searchTerm.compareTo(b.searchTerm);
  },
  itemSubmitted: (item) {
    setState(() {
      _searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item.name;
      country = item.country;
      colour = item.colour;
      name = item.name;
      variety = item.variety;
    });
  },
  key: key,
  suggestions: FruitsViewModel.fruits,
  clearOnSubmit: false,
);
```

My issue is that this package doesn't seem to allow me to add a cursor, where the standard TextField does. Ideally, I would like to be able to add it and control its size and style. At the moment, since there is no cursor, it is impossible to know if the user can start searching or not. Does anyone know how to add a cursor with this package? Or could perhaps suggest another package that behaves in exactly the same way, but has a cursor? Thanks.

Comment: Although I haven't tried `AutoCompleteTextField` plugin inside `appbar`, but if you tap on the field inside appbar, do you see the cursor or don't ?

Comment: I don't, no. All the functionality is there but the cursor isn't. I thought it might be because my appBar is white (and perhaps the cursor would be too) but it isn't - changing the appBar colour doesn't make it show.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to raise this as an issue against the plugin repo to see if it supports placing the field inside appbar. Otherwise, the cursor is displayed if you place it inside scaffold's body.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll do that and see what I can find.

Comment: I just loaded my app in the Android simulator to test it and I've found that a cursor does appear there (a blue bar, still not customisable). It seems to be that it only doesn't appear in iOS. I've raised a query, so I'll see what happens.